# Bluetooth keyboard fails to connect xubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, bluetooth

Attempts to connect an apple wireless keyboard to ubuntu, via a usb bluetooth adapter fail. I've tried several different keyboards with same result. Using bluetoothctl and all seems to go well until:

```
>Attempting to connect to 60:FB:42:09:BE:94  "the keyboard"
>[CHG] Device 60:FB:42:09:BE:94 Connected: yes
>[CHG] Device 60:FB:42:09:BE:94 ServicesResolved: yes
>Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.InProgress
>[CHG] Device 60:FB:42:09:BE:94 ServicesResolved: no
>[CHG] Device 60:FB:42:09:BE:94 Connected: no
```

Any ideas of what is missing or misconfigured?

UPDATE: In case it might be useful - problem is missing kernel module, hidp, which handles protocol for keyboards, etc. xubuntu was installed w/o any bluetooth devices in the machine so that module wasn't inserted. Adding it to /etc/modules solves the problem.
If the bluetooth device is from Apple, you also need to add the hid-apple module.